# What sets a child's STDERR, STDOUT, and STDIN?

Tags: file-descriptors, fork

If a program runs `fork()` what sets standard streams `STDOUT`, `STDIN` and `STDERR`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stdin, stdout and stderr are inherited from the parent process.  It's up to the child process to change them to point to new files if that is needed.

From the `fork(2)` man page:

```
   *  The  child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file descrip‐
      tors.  Each file descriptor in the child refers  to  the  same  open
      file  description (see open(2)) as the corresponding file descriptor
      in the parent.
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kyle Jones states, they're propagated from the parent process. If you're asking *how* to set them in a child, you're looking for [`freopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen).